# Why do characters keep getting deleted from this InputField?

Tags: performance-tuning, front-end, dynamic

I have a function which takes relatively long to compute.

```
longtask[str_String] := (Pause[0.5]; ToUpperCase[str])
```

I need to show the result of this function "live" as applied to an input dynamically typed into a text box.  I need typing to be fluid and fast.  I expect the output to follow with some lag.

Here's an example:

```
DynamicModule[{str = ""},
 Deploy@Column[{
    InputField[Dynamic[str], String, FieldSize -> {30, 2}, ContinuousAction -> True],
    Dynamic[
     longtask[str],
     SynchronousUpdating -> False]
    }
   ]
 ]
```

The problem: Sometimes the character that I just typed gets immediately deleted.  Why?  How can I prevent this?

To test this, just quickly type any sentence into the text box.  For example, if I type "Once upon a time there was a little girl.", I get something like this:

[image]

If you watch carefully while typing, you will notice that all characters appear, but some of them get immediately removed.

Is there a way to prevent this without affecting the responsiveness of the input field?

---

To put it differently: I am dealing with slow evaluations in `Dynamic`. I want `ContinuousUpdating -> True`. I understand that the output will respond slowly to the input, but I do not want this to affect the performance of the input.  Is this technically possible?

Part of the reason why I want `ContinuousUpdating -> True` is that an `InputField` won't update otherwise until it loses focus.

Comment: @Kuba I didn't realize that.  I can actually do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess it is a problem with FE-Kernel synchornization of variables state (`str` copy is here and there).

Notice that `str` which is not a `DynamicModule's` variable works well. Quite often it is not a major problem. Last value won't be preserved across sessions but at least it can be properly initialized in `Initialization`.

One needs to pick a less conflict prone name e.g. `` MyPackage`Gui`specificname `` but the code itself doesn't have to be changed:

```
With[{str := MyPackage`Gui`whatever}, 
 DynamicModule[{}, 
  Deploy@Column[{InputField[Dynamic[str], String, 
      FieldSize -> {30, 2}, ContinuousAction -> True], 
     Dynamic[longtask[str], SynchronousUpdating -> False]}], 
  Initialization :> (str = "")]
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks! http://i.stack.imgur.com/A602t.gif

Comment: @Szabolcs Nice!